# Cannot get value from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, transfer

So in my PHP file I create a JSON Object which I need to get to my Javascript file for processing. I can't seem to transfer anything however, not even with a simple string like this:-

*index.php*

```
<?php
  $cookie= "blueberry cake";
?>;
```

*script.js*

```
   var details = "<?php echo $cookie; ?>";
   function myFunction() { 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = details;
   }
```

*index.html*

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>antgus</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Welcome to my page! </h1>

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>


</body>
```

I got a button in my HTML, so when I press it the function myFunction get's called. It's supposed to change a p element with id "demo" to the string "blueberry cake"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

I now have it working except one thing, I can't pass a JSON object to a function i Javascript. The console throws an error saying that the arguments is wrong, it thinks I am passing multiple strings.
*index.php*

```
    <?php
    $test = "blue";
    $logLines = file('../../../home/shares/flower_hum/humid.log');
    $entries = array_map("clean",$logLines);
    $finalOutput = [
        'humid'   => $entries
    ];
    function clean($string){
        return json_decode(rtrim(trim($string),','),true);
    }

    $json = json_encode($finalOutput, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    echo $json; //displays valid JSON, I have checked it.
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <title>antgus</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Welcome to my page! Down below you can see the data:</p>
        <button type="button" onclick='myFunction("<?php echo $json ?>")'>Try it</button>
        <p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

*script.js*

```
function myFunction(jsonObject) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "INCOMING DATA:";
    alert(jsonObject);
}
    enter code here
```

Comment: update your full code.html+php+javascript.

Comment: You need to pass `details` as `arguments` as `myFunction(details)`

Comment: PHP servers are not interpreting PHP code in files with the extension `.js` by default. if you change your script file's name to `script.php`, the PHP code will be executed.

Comment: Where you include `index.php` file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to consider:-

1.External js will not work as you tried.

2.When you call a javascript function directly through `onclick` code then you have to pass data also for working further.

A working code sample:-

***index.php:-***

```
<?php
  $cookie= "blueberry cake";
?>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>antgus</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to my page! </h1>

<button type="button" onclick='myFunction("<?php echo $cookie; ?>")'>Try it</button>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
```

***script.js:-***

```
function myFunction(details) { 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = details;
}
```

Output at my local end:-

before click:- http://prntscr.com/ci94s9

After click:-http://prntscr.com/ci94w9

Comment: So I should have HTML, JS and PHP in the same file? Doesn't that get cluttered?

Comment: I tried your first example but it prints out "<?php echo $cookie; ?>"

Comment: @lolzDoe  check my current code. i have taken your code sample and changed it. use it

Comment: Hm, I thinks it's beacuse I still used my HTML file. So I out the HTML inside the PHP and have an externa JS file? But I still can't get this to work. Could you create a gist and copy in all your code?

Answer (score 1):

The external js file will not be parsed as php meaning that you cannot access that variable. You can save your js as php (NOT RECOMMENDED). alternatively a)

include that function at the bottom of the bottom of the php page:

```
<?php
  $cookie= "blueberry cake";
?>;
    //js further down the same page
  <script>
    var details = "<?php echo $cookie; ?>";
   function myFunction() { 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = details;
    }
 </script>
```

or b) declare a global variable in the php page so that the external js can access it:

```
//php page
    <?php
      $cookie= "blueberry cake";
    ?>;
<script> var details = "<?php echo $cookie; ?>";</script>


//js file
       function myFunction() { 
          //details will be accessible since it has been declared in the global space of the index.php page
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = details;
       }
```

Comment: I tried your second example but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

This should work perfectly:

> With In-Document JS:

```
<?php
     $cookie= "blueberry cake";
?>;

<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var details = "<?php echo $cookie; ?>";
            function myFunction() {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = details;
            }
        </script>
        <title>antgus</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Welcome to my page!</h1>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
    </body>
```

> With External JS:

```
<?php
     $cookie= "blueberry cake";
?>;

<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var details = "<?php echo $cookie; ?>";
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"> </script>
        <title>antgus</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Welcome to my page!</h1>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
    </body>
```

> **script.js File:**

```
    function myFunction() {
         // HAS ACCESS TO details WHICH IS ON THE GLOBAL SCOPE
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = details;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Not sure why, I got all the files in the same folder. I tried both with inline js and external.

Comment: @loizDoe     Your Problem is the file `script.js`. You cannot do PHP Operations there. See how it is done here. You create a Javascript Variable:`details` on the Global Scope and then you can access it from within any other Script like `script.js`... but the definition of the `details` should not be in the external file... (***only accessed in those files not declared using php***)

Answer (score 1):

Encode the json object using `json_encode`, that is

```
<script> var details = "<?php echo json_encode($cookie); ?>";</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around php, dude. You are assigning string instead of the php variable value.

```
var details = "'" + <?php echo $cookie; ?> + "'";
```

This will assign the actual `$cookie` value instead of the string `'<? php echo $cookie; ?>'`.

Comment: I have tried removing them but this causes my JS file not to execute at all.

Comment: Ah.... well, you cannot really use both js and php inside file with .js extension. You could put this particular part of code inside your index.php and inside `<script></script>` tag. Php would execute on the server and substitute the $cookie value and js would have the value ready when executed in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The php-script is run server-side, and the javascript is run client-side, and the two do not share some kind of scope.

In other words, the `$cookie` variable is assigned a value in php, but it isn't used. Then you use a variable in your javascript with the same name (but completely unrelated to the php variable), but since it is never assigned anything, it's `undefined`.

gavgrif offers some solutions to fix this.